# URL to reboot a WebSTAR DPC2100R2 cable modem with curl?

Tags: automation, cable-modem, curl

Does anyone know what the magic URL is for rebooting a WebSTAR DPC2100R2 with curl? I used to have a SurfBoard, and the curl command:

```
curl http://192.168.100.1/reset.htm?reset_modem=Restart%20Cable%20Modem
```

Would reset the modem. Sure, I can go power cycle it manually, but it's in the basement and I'm lazy :-).

I did find out the URL to [elevate the access permission](http://www.borfast.com/blog/scientific-atlanta-webstar-2203c-how-access-locked-pages), but nothing about rebooting/resetting yet.

Comment: Can you do it from the webUI? If so, try [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what the URL, or what request, sends when you hit the reset button.

Comment: No, the webui for this model doesn't have any advanced management or configuration, otherwise I'd just read the HTML for the form (thats how I found the surfboard URL long ago).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
curl http://192.168.100.1/goform/gscan -d SADownStartingFrequency=687000000
```

The response should look like this:

```
<html lang="en"><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="20; URL=/system.asp"><body BGCOLOR="#CCCCCC" TEXT=black><HR><h1>The device has been reset...<a href="/system.asp">RELOAD</a></h1></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an article ([Reboot WebSTAR DPC2100R2 Cable Internet Modem](http://onlinetechadvice.blogspot.com/2010/10/reboot-webstar-dpc2100r2-cable-internet.html)) which showed me how to use the command in Windows XP:

> 1. First you will need to [download cURL for Windows](http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/curl-7.21.2-devel-mingw32.zip)
> 2. Now extract the curl archive you downloaded to your D: drive, you can use any drive but just make sure you continue to use the same drive in the next steps.
> 3. Open a Command Prompt (Start > Run > type "cmd" without quotes and press enter)
> 4. Navigate to the drive where you extracted the cURL program; if it's on the D: drive type D: and press enter. Now type:
>
>    ```
>     cd curl-7.21.2-devel-mingw32\bin
>    ```
>
>    Your Command Prompt should now be showing this path:
>
>    ```
>     D:\curl-7.21.2-devel-mingw32\bin>
>    ```
> 5. Copy and paste the following command into the Command Prompt window - when you press enter your modem will reset:
>
>    ```
>     curl http://192.168.100.1/goform/gscan -d SADownStartingFrequency=687000000
>    ```

Answer (score 0):

192.168.100.1/gscan.asp works for me
(from http://forums.cable-modem.net/index.php?action=vthread&forum=2&topic=1001&page=2).

I suspect this is a frame from a whole hidden admin interface though, and I can't find the rest of it!